# How do I have a program reference an internal random result and apply it to a list to print a result?

Tags: python, random, dice

Ok, I need some help here. I'm attempting to write a program that rolls a die internally (randrange), which is referenced to a list that will then print the result onto the screen

Example: User inputs "1", activating the dice roll. The program rolls a 2 and checks a list to see what 2 means. 2 means Medium, so it then prints "Medium"

However, I can't figure out where I'd look for a tutorial on this (as I can't figure out what I'd even search for), and everyone I ask gets confused by the question. So I come to you with a pasted set of code. Here's a pastebin for better viewing: http://pastebin.com/PGEmNqTm

```
import random

def Main() :

    print TESTING
    print
    print
    print "1 1d4"

    sum = raw_input("> ")

    if sum == '1':
        numberr = random.randrange(1, 5)
            if numberr = 1
                print "Small"
            elif numberr = 2
                print "Medium"
            elif numberr = 3
                print "Large"
            elif numberr = 4
                print "Huge"

while 1:
    input = raw_input("Press Enter to continue or q to quit").upper()
    if input == 'Q': break
    elif input == '' : Main()
```

Comment: I have a feeling I may have to research Dictionaries, but I'm not sure if it's necessary.

Comment: Your feeling is spot on. Instead of the `if`s you should be doing something like `myNum = ({1:'Small', 2:'Medium', 3:'Large', 4:'Huge'})` - try checking out this: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: `raw_imput`? Also your input from the user is in a variable called `sum`? also your checks need, `==` not `=` and `:` at the end of the `if/elif`. Why not paste your code here instead of typing it out.  Not sure what your question is either, what do you want, and what do you have instead?

Comment: Ok...but...how do I get it to print the dictionary result after the roll? I'm reading that document but...I can't figure out how to apply that...

Comment: @rm I did paste it here but it didn't recognize it as code until I did the whole "4 spaces" stuff. I'm new here so I'm probably missing something for all that. 

And I figured they needed == but the code wasn't working anyways so I figured I'd give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from a few small details, your code seems pretty good as it is.

Those are:

- Your `if numberr == x:` lines shouldn't be indented because they're not part of
  a new block.
- You need to double the `=` sign when doing a test: `if number == 1:`
- You need a colon for an `if` (which you knew, but it was missing on some
  lines).
- `raw_input` not `raw_imput`
- Quotes around "TESTING"

Here's the code with those fixes:

```
import random

def Main() :

    print "TESTING"
    print
    print
    print "1 1d4"

    sum = raw_input("> ")

    if sum == '1':
        numberr = random.randrange(1, 5)
        if numberr == 1:
            print "Small"
        elif numberr == 2:
            print "Medium"
        elif numberr == 3:
            print "Large"
        elif numberr == 4:
            print "Huge"

while 1:
    input = raw_input("Press Enter to continue or q to quit").upper()
    if input == 'Q': break
    elif input == '' : Main()
```

So I'd say you already seem to have it right.

(Also Vishal's advice is good too)

Comment: *reads over* ok, so it was mostly just a set of simple mistakes, then? I ran yours and it worked just fine so I guess it was just off by a few things. All right, then I don't feel so bad, ha! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

May be you can leverage from this example:

```
import random

def roll(num):
    return  {
        1: "Small",
        2: "Medium",
        3: "Large",
        4: "Huge",
        5: "Huge+",
        6: "Huge++"
    }[num]

print roll(random.randrange(1, 7))
```

Comment: `random.randrange(1, 6)` won't ever return `6`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import random

myNum = ({1:'Small', 2:'Medium', 3:'Large', 4:'Huge'})

def main():
    mysum = raw_input("> ")
    if mysum == '1':
        numberr = random.randrange(1,5)
        print(myNum[numberr])

while 1:
    myinput = raw_input("Press Enter to continue or q to quit")
    if myinput == 'Q':
        break
    elif myinput == '' :
        main()
```

Be careful with naming your variable names reserved keywords!

Comment: Ok, so that's how you'd use a more dictionary-oriented format for this then... all right, that's pretty helpful to know, thanks!